# Custom Knockout Binding Handler not showing bindings

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Here is my custom binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.alert = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) {
        $(element).attr({ style: "display:none" });

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { with: valueAccessor() }, context);

        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var data = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

        if (data) {
            $(element).attr({ "class": "alert " + ko.unwrap(data.success) });
            $(element).show();
        }
        else
            $(element).hide();
    }
};
```

Here is my alert obj that I pass into the binding:

```
var alertObj = {
    success: "",
    image: "",
    message: ""
};

var initialDataObj = {
    success: "alert-success",
    fail: "alert-danger"
};

var Alert = function (initialData) {
    var self = this;

    self.success = initialData.success;
    self.successImage = initialData.successImage;
    self.fail = initialData.fail;
    self.failImage = initialData.failImage;

    self.setAlert = function (success, message) {
        var alert = {};
        $.extend(alert, alertObj);

        alert.success = success ? self.success : self.fail;
        alert.image = success ? self.successImage : self.failImage;
        alert.message = message;

        return alert;
    };
}
```

This is how I set my alert:

```
self.alert(alert.setAlert(true, "Role removed"));
```

Here is my html:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" data-bind="alert: $root.alert">
    <img data-bind="attr: { src: $root.image }" alt="" width="16" style="float: left;">
    <p style="float: left; margin-left: 10px;" data-bind="text: $root.message"></p>
    <div style="clear: both;">
    </div>
</div>
```

It currently choose the correct class for the alert, but it doesn't show the picture or the text, somewhere the bindings are getting lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By simple logics $root is not necessary when you getting access to `image` and `message` since binding context inside the alert block is `alert` object returned by `.setAlert`

```
<div class="alert alert-success" data-bind="alert: $root.alert">
    <img data-bind="attr: { src: image }" alt="" width="16" style="float: left;">
    <p style="float: left; margin-left: 10px;" data-bind="text: message"></p>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Pretty sure it will help.

Comment: ahhhhh yeah, haha so silly, I was so tired when I looked at it last night, just skipped over that!